# Error while classifying the data set: Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a data set which has 158 columns and 3.1 million rows, I'm writing a classifier program to analyse that data set in `Jupyter lab`. Here my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import model_selection, preprocessing, feature_selection, ensemble, linear_model, metrics, decomposition
from lime import lime_tabular
dtf = pd.read_csv('hackathon_train_data1.csv')
dtf.head()
'''
Recognize whether a column is numerical or categorical.
:parameter
    :param dtf: dataframe - input data
    :param col: str - name of the column to analyze
    :param max_cat: num - max number of unique values to recognize a column as categorical
:return
    "cat" if the column is categorical or "num" otherwise
'''
def utils_recognize_type(dtf, col, max_cat=20):
    if (dtf[col].dtype == "O") | (dtf[col].nunique() < max_cat):
        return "cat"
    else:
        return "num"
dic_cols = {col:utils_recognize_type(dtf, col, max_cat=158) for col in dtf.columns}
heatmap = dtf.isnull()
for k,v in dic_cols.items():
 if v == "num":
   heatmap[k] = heatmap[k].apply(lambda x: 0.5 if x is False else 1)
 else:
   heatmap[k] = heatmap[k].apply(lambda x: 0 if x is False else 1)
sns.heatmap(heatmap, cbar=False).set_title('Dataset Overview')
plt.show()
print("\033[1;37;40m Categerocial ", "\033[1;30;41m Numeric ", "\033[1;30;47m NaN ")
```

My code works fine till this point. It prints the heat map to visualize column types.
Now, I'm trying to plot `univariate distributions`.

```
dtf = dtf.set_index("sohf_ord_nbr")
```

Then I verified the indexes by using this code

```
dtf.head()
```

Then I attempted to plot a bar graph by using this code:

```
ax = dtf[y].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind="barh")
```

This threw error as given below.

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 ax = dtf[y].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind="barh")
> NameError: name 'y' is not defined

So I defined `y` as follows...

```
y = "y"
ax = dtf[y].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind="barh")
```

This threw an exception as given below...

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
> 3079             try:
> -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> 3081             except KeyError as err:
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> KeyError: 'y'
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 ax = dtf[y].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind="barh")
> c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in **getitem**(self, key)
> 3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
> 3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
> 3025             if is_integer(indexer):
> 3026                 indexer = [indexer]
> c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> 3081             except KeyError as err:
> -> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
> 3083
> 3084         if tolerance is not None:
> KeyError: 'y'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: check if `y` is present in the output of `print(dtf.columns)`

Comment: Oh... I checked and changed value of `y` accordingly, it worked. Thank you